# not work condition onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged

I have an issue with the following condition:

`if (Cuadrado.isChecked() == true)`

This is the full code:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    String dato5 = DatoMath.getText().toString();

    if (Cubo.isChecked()==true) {

        if (dato5.equals("")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            int datofinal = Integer.parseInt(dato5);
            int final3 = (int) Math.pow(datofinal, 2);

            Resultado.setText("" + final3);};

    if (Cuadrado.isChecked() == true) {

        if (dato5.equals("")) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no hay datossssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();

        } else {
                    int datofinal2 = Integer.parseInt(dato5);
                    int final4 = (int) Math.pow(datofinal2, 3);

                    Resultado.setText("" + final4);

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you intentionally complicating your code, you can simply write:

```
if (Cubo.isChecked())
{
//do whatever you want to do
}
```

The isChecked method returns a boolean so you can directly write it inside that if condition

And one more thing, why have you put a semi-colon[ ; ] after your else statements closing brace[ } ], replace that semicolon with another closing brace[ } ]

Comment: thanks for your help very effective, Part of 'running perfect cubo,  but part of the cuadrado is not working

Comment: pressing on cuadrado makes no function do not understand why, instead pressing cubo if you develop the corresponding logic.

Comment: i just saw one thing, why have you put a semi-colon(;) after your else statements closing brace( } ), replace that semicolon with another closing brace( } )

Comment: anytime dude, i should add that to my answer too, so that anyone viewing the answer would get the complete solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override 
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
switch(checkedId){
 case R.id.rbtn1:
 // radio button 1 checked related code
 break;
 case R.id.rbtn2:
 // radio button 2 checked related code
 break;
 }

}
```